# Outlook and Gmail - how to search for old messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap

I've Outlook connected to Gmail via IMAP with 6 months cache. How can I search older messages (which are still in the cloud)?

The basic need is that I have to free up space in Gmail. I made a search in for large messages with this command: "larger:20M" and it's ok to find most space consuming messages.

Now I want to delete attachments but keep message body (for reference and possible future legal use). It seems not possible from within Gmail so I'm trying via Outlook, which allows to delete attachments only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, I'm afraid that we could not find the older messages which are still in the Gmail server with outlook search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BEFORE`, so for stuff say older than 1st January 2020 use

`BEFORE:01/01/2020`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work this way. Messages are not in local cache and what I need is outlook to search on the cloud for old messages (and locally for cached messages)